# Linking and assigning struct elements to random nodes

Tags: c, algorithm

This is the problem:

> Basically, you will be given a LARGE file (think 20000+ lines of text) that contains the following:
> Line 1: `<number_of_nodes> <number of edges>`
> The rest: `<Source> <Destination> <Cost>`
> Your goal is to figure out a memory efficient way to create the structure(s) that will allow you to associate the nodes to its connected nodes. These connections are bidirectional.
>
> The user should be allowed to input any location/node and the program must output all the neighbors of the node and the corresponding cost from the input node to each of the neighbors.

*note: that |LARGE FILES| contain 25000 lines of text in this format

```
integer integer integer
```

Here's the supposed output:

```
Number of nodes is 25000

Enter a node to examine: 0
Neighbors of node 0 are:
Node 1 with cost 450
Node 100 with cost 1130

Enter a node to examine:0
Neighbors of node 0 are:
Node 4 with cost 850
Node 91 with cost 304


Enter a node to examine: 0
Neighbors of node 0 are:
Node 3 with cost 230
Node 11 with cost 330

Enter a node to examine: exit
```

And here's what I've tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct graph {
    int src;
    int dest;
    int cost;
}PathEdge;

int main()
{
    int nlines, i,v;
    char r;
    int ecost,ebegin, eend;

    scanf(“%s”,&nlines);

    PathEdge[nlines + 1];

    for(i = 0; i < nlines; i++) {
        scanf("%d, %d, %d\n", &ebegin, &eend, &ecost);
        edges[i].begin = ebegin;
        edges[i].end = eend;
        edges[i].cost = ecost;
        struct town
        {
            struct town *north;
            int name[25000];
        };
        struct town *root, *current;
        root = (struct town *) malloc (sizeof (struct town));
        root->north = NULL;
        strcpy (root->name,ecost);
        current = (struct town *) malloc (sizeof (struct town));
        current->north = root;
        strcpy (current->name, ecost);
        strcpy(ecost,”Node %d”,i);
    }

    printf(“%d”,sizeof(int name));
    printf(“Please enter a node that you want to examine. If you want to exit, please press ‘X’.\n”);
    scanf(“%c”,&r);

    switch(r)
    {
    case ‘X’:
    case ‘x’:
        printf(“You entered a wrong value. Gomen. Try again.\n”);
        break;
    default:
        if(0<r<25000)
        {
            printf(“You have accessed node %d\n”,r);
            printf(“Its neighboring nodes are %d\n %d\n”,ecost[nlines+1],ecost[nlines+2]);
        }
        else
        {
            printf(“Invalid input again. Please do try again. Thanks\n”);
        }
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: and what is wrong with your try?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `strcpy(ecost,”Node %d”,i);` that does not work. Please learn about `sprintf()`, or even better: `snprintf()` .

Comment: **"create the structure(s) that will allow you to associate the nodes to its connected nodes. These connections are bidirectional."** To me says create a **doubly-linked-list** (or similar iterative structure with reference to **previous/next** members) so that the user request any node and you would then be able to provide the cost to the neighbors, etc. Also **do not cast the return of `malloc`**. (i.e. `(struct town *) malloc` should simply be `malloc`).